# Python ee outputs error

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

After executing following code in python

```
import ee
import geemap

ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()
```

I get an Error on Initialize

> RefreshError: ('invalid_scope: Bad Request', {'error':
> 'invalid_scope', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'})

And so the following code doesn't work too

```
dem = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003')
xy = ee.Geometry.Point([86.9250, 27.9881])
elev = dem.sample(xy, 30).first().get('elevation').getInfo()
print('Mount Everest elevation (m):', elev)
```

Error which I get is

> EEException: Earth Engine client library not initialized. Run
> `ee.Initialize()`

Comment: There are steps outlined here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/python_install

Comment: @enolan well, I've looked through this one and it kinda works sometimes